# Find significance level of hypothesis

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I'm given two random sample datasets of sample size n=20, where the first dataset represents the weights of random boys, and second group represents weights of random girls. I need to find the significance level of saying that boys on average weight more than girls.
To solve this problem I'm assuming that the null hypothesis of saying that boys weight the same as girls (no difference) is true, and building a sampling distribution of **differences** of weights between boys and girls with the mean difference of 0 (since I'm assuming that there is no difference in general).
I've calculated the standard deviation for this sampling distribution and I know the **difference** of mean weights of two **sample** datasets (which is supposedly a part of this sampling distribution).
Now if I divide the difference of sample means by standard deviation of this sampling distribution what value do I get? Is that a t-value? How do I find the significance level from that?

Comment: You do not find the significance level, $\alpha$, you *choose* it, ostensibly so that it reflects your willingness to make a Type I error (i.e. to reject the null hypothesis when the null hypothesis is true). On the other hand the $p$-value measures how unlikely your test statistic, $t$, is to be observed assuming that the null hypothesis is true. If $p < \alpha/2$ ($\alpha/2$ because two-sided test), then you will reject the null hypothesis at the $\alpha$ level of significance, and conclude that population mean weights in boys do not equal population mean weights in girls.

Comment: @Alexis I'm confused between the p-value and sigma. Is the sigma a value from the sampling distribution and the p-value is the probability of getting that value?

Comment: Can you provide a citation of the use of $\sigma$ you want to understand better? The term gets used in several different ways.

Comment: I want to understand the sigma in the context of significance level. In some places the p-value and in other places sigma.

Comment: Please provide a *citation* or *link* using the term in a way that you do not understand. Again: $\sigma$ gets used in several ways, so such a citation or link will help prospective answerers speak to your interests.

Comment: @Alexis Your comment is entirely unhelpful. The p-value is the "significance level" for a neo-Fisherian significance test. It is not chosen in advance. Not every question is answered by a Neyman–Pearsonian hypothesis test. In fact, very few should be! See here for the full story: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/164_2019_286

Comment: 1/2 @MichaelLew Your "entirely unhelpful" is overblown and out of place given that the OP is asking about [significance level](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/statistical-significance/info) in the context of hypothesis testing. Regardless of your own aversion to hypothesis tests, significance level is an *a priori* tolerance for type I errors assuming the null hypothesis is true, while the $p$ value describes the probability of observing a test statistic as or more extreme as that observed assuming the null hypothesis is true. I find your muddling of $\alpha$ and $p$ is unhelpful.

Comment: 2/2 @MichaelLew While one *could* interpret *p* value of any given hypothesis test as "the limit of significance" for that specific test, that does not in any way override the conceptual distinction between [$\alpha$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_significance) and $p$.

Comment: @Alexis I do not see any mention of hypothesis testing in the question. I think that you may have read that into it all by yourself.

Comment: @MichaelLew The title is "Find significance level of **hypothesis**"

Comment: @Alex This will be my last comment here. What does a significance test deal with if not the significance of a hypothesis? Hypothesis tests allow a programatic 'decision' to be made regarding a hypothesis, but they are not the only statistical method that deal with hypotheses!

Answer (score 1):

Welch's approximate $T$ is given by: $$T = \frac{(\bar{X}_1-\bar{X}_2) - (\mu_1-\mu_2)}{\sqrt{\frac{S^2_1}{n_1}+\frac{S^2_2}{n_2}}}. $$
$T$ has an approximate $T$ distribution with $\nu^*$ degrees of freedom, where $$\nu^* = \frac{\left( \frac{S^2_1}{n_1}+\frac{S^2_2}{n_2}\right)^2} {\frac{S^4_1}{n^2_1(n_1-1)} + \frac{S^4_2}{n^2_2(n_2-1)}}.$$
It isn't immediately apparent, but is true that $\min (n_1, n_2)-1 \leq \nu^* \leq n_1+n_2-2$.  In your circumstance, where the sample sizes are equal, the pooled $T$ test is rather robust to distributional assumptions.  You won't go far wrong with the pooled $T$ test.